# Bootstrap navbar breaking at 'xs' size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, responsiveness

I'm using a bootstrap navbar and when I resize the window for mobile, my navbar loses the normal content and becomes non rounded. I'm unsure what's causing it. I've removed any overrides and the issue still exists.

I'm using the bootstrap sass port with compass.

It looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpNJ0.png

It should look like this:

https://i.imgur.com/FE8VS8d.png

Jade:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default
    .container
        .collapse.navbar-collapse
            .navbar-header
                strong.navbar-brand example
            div.navbar-right
                ul.nav.navbar-nav
                    li 
                        a(href="/") Home
                    li 
                        a(href='https://github.com/') GitHub    
                    li 
                        a(href=loggedin ? '/account' : '/login') #{loggedin ? 'My Account' : 'Sign In'}
```

No CSS as using just bootstrap CSS for the navbar

Comment: Added my jade code :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a media query on small width to element the border-radius.

Check the CSS for the media query at the point the border disappears and check to see if there is a `border-radius:0;` or similar in the css for the navbar and take it out

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had half configured a 'collapse' navbar which was what was breaking.